# How do I invoke jq inside awk?

Tags: awk, grep, quoting, jq

Essentially I have a file.log as follow

```
blah blah
blah blah
Hello world | {"foo": "bar"}
blah blah
Hello earth | {"foo1": "bar1"}
```

Now my goal is to write some shell commands to have desire output like this:

```
Hello earth | "bar"
Hello earth | "bar1"
```

Currently this is what I have:

```
grep Hello file.log | awk -F "|" '{print $1, system("jq " $2)}'
```

However calling jq is giving me this error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
bin:application   
jq: 1 compile error
```

I am thinking that its because inside system(), my $12 is stripped off all the quotation character (") thus JQ fail to recognize its json.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

#### You have several problems here

- `system` doesn't return something to print, it returns the exit value of the command you executed (0 if everything ran fines). You will see your JSON decoded data and then a line like `Hello earth 0`
- the double quotes in your JSON string are swallowed by the shell. The resulting command you are executing is `jq {foo: bar}` (two arguments, JSON no longer quoted)
- if `$2` contains special characters like `$`, your shell will interpret them
- even with proper quoting, `jq` is not called like that, it expects a filter as first argument (say '`.`') and it expects the JSON input to be read from a file, or from standard input
- building a command from the logs and executing it has huge security implication (what if `$2` was `; rm -rf ~`?). Better avoid it if you can.

The security issue set aside, here is an `awk` code that will work most of the time:

```
awk -F "|" '{ printf "%s", $1; system("echo \x27" $2 "\x27 | jq .")}'
```

What it does is send `$2` enclosed in single-quotes (`\x27`) to `jq` through stdin.

#### Issues remain, though

- if `$2` contains a single quote, it will break the whole command
- if `$2` begins with a dash (unlikely) it will be interpreted as an option to `echo` (we may use the `printf` command instead of `echo`)
- the security issue already mentioned (e.g. if `$2` contains `...'; rm -r ~; : ' ...` anywhere in the string)

#### Now a better `awk` code

```
awk -F "|" '{ printf "%s", $1; print $2 | "jq ."; close("jq ."); }'
```

Since `$2` is sent to a `jq` process through stdin, but now using an `awk` pipe, it is no longer interpreted by the shell, solving all the issues above. The `jq` command must be closed (terminated) at each line, hence the call to `close()`.

Answer (score 2):

[xhienne gave a good overview](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395304/116858) of the issues with the existing code, and a good alternative for what you want to accomplish.

The following is another alternative:  Don't try to call `jq` from `awk` at all, but let the `awk` script create proper JSON output.

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { print "[" } $2 != "" { if (t != "") print t ","; t = $2 } END { print t, "]" }' file | jq .
[
  {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "foo1": "bar1"
  }
]
```

The `awk` code, by itself, will generate the following JSON array from the found JSON objects (given the example in the question):

```
[
 {"foo": "bar"},
 {"foo1": "bar1"} ]
```

This allows you to work more freely with `jq` without making your script too difficult to maintain and understand.

The juggling with the `t` variable in the script is just a way of making sure that we don't get a trailing comma after the last JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution , without using awk and only *jq*

The trick is to use **--raw-input** , that will read the file as a array of string  .

So for each line , test if the symbol **|** is here 
cut the string into , and parse the part as json string

```
jq -j --raw-input  '
    . as $line | 
    if index("|") >= 0  
    then  
      [ .[:index("|")-1] ,.[index("|")+2:] ]  
    else 
      empty
    end | 
   [ .[0] , ( .[1] | fromjson | to_entries | .[0].value ) ] |
   .[0] , " | \"" ,.[1] , "\"\n" '  /tmp/file.log
```

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR:

```bsh
jq -r -R '
  select(contains(" | ")) |
  split(" | ") |
  .[0] as $text |
  (.[1] | fromjson | to_entries | .[0].value ) as $json_obj_value |
  "\($text) | \($json_obj_value)"
' yourlogfile.log
```

### Complete answer

Most people don't realize quite how powerful `jq` is (though the same can be said about `awk`).

As [Kusalananda thoughtfully pointed out in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395309/43344), your best friend here is [the `-R` flag](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Invokingjq), that will read the input line by line as json strings instead of a json object. With that we are free to treat the string within `jq` only, without any need for `awk` at all.

Here is how the documentation describes it as of version **1.6**:

> `--raw-input` / `-R:`
>
> Don't parse the input as JSON. Instead, each line of text is passed to the filter as a string. If combined with `--slurp`, then the entire input is passed to the filter as a single long string.

For your desired output you will also need [the `-r` flag](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Invokingjq), which makes it print bare strings instead of json strings in the terminal.

Again from the docs

> `--raw-output` / `-r`:
>
> With this option, if the filter's result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

So with that out of the way, there are a few ways to tackle this in `jq`.

As [EchoMike444 already answered with a more imperative way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507036/43344), I tried to use a different approach, which was a little more pipeliney.

```bsh
jq -r -R '
  select(contains(" | ")) |
  split(" | ") |
  .[0] as $text |
  (.[1] | fromjson | to_entries | .[0].value ) as $json_obj_value |
  "\($text) | \($json_obj_value)"
' yourlogfile.log
```

Basically we

1. Throw out any line without " | " in it
2. Split each line into two parts
3. Put the left part in a `$text` binding for legibility
4. Parse the right part into json, get it's first value and put it in a `$json_obj_value` binding for legibility
5. Print a string `"$text | $json_obj_value"` (`\(foo)` is how you do interpolation on `jq`)

If you want it as compact as possible, you can use

```
jq -Rr 'select(contains(" | "))|split(" | ")|"\(.[0]) | \(.[1]|fromjson|to_entries|.[0].value)"' yourlogfile.log
```

That will be smaller but also harder to read. Which is the best will depend on taste and use-case.